# Allow a user to "create a new Activity" for themselves?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've completed the mini tutorial Android Studio provides for itself, so as far as I'm aware, there's no way for a user to create a new Activity themselves. My goal is for the main activity to have a button which, when pressed, allows the user to create a new page, fill it with information, and then have the main activity link to the new page. I might be thinking about it the wrong way (maybe that's not an activity?), but can someone let me know how I can do that? Thank you!

Comment: You would probably have to link to a blank activity and then pass in all your 'information' to the blank activity and build the UI all programmatically from code behind.  What kind of information are you accepting?  You're likely going about this the wrong way but I can't tell from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have them "create a new activity", but you could do something that appears to do so to the user.

For example, you could create an activity `CustomActivity` which is built up programmatically from a data structure you define `CustomActivityConfiguration`.

The user could set up multiple instances of the `CustomActivityConfiguration` object by whatever GUI you provide to do that, and when they click "Launch My Activity A", for example, you launch `CustomActivity` and pass the appropriate configuration to it.

Comment: This sounds like what I want to do, thank you! Sorry to keep asking questions, but how would I go about setting up CustomActivityConfiguration?

Comment: That depends entirely on what type and level of customization you want to allow. For example, if you just have a few possible configurations you could put all the possible Views in your `CustomActivity` and just set their visibility in `onCreate` based on some booleans in the configuration. If you're letting the user position them or add new ones you'll have to get a lot more information (what to put, how to position it, etc...).

Comment: If you're going to build it up completely flexibly I'd suggest going through the steps of building a single random instance of `CustomActivity` programmatically and using that to figure out what pieces of information you need to get from the user.

Comment: If this helps with your question, consider accepting it and asking followup questions as you try to implement it.